# Fetch Failing with Apostrophe/Tick Mark Character ' in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, fetch

I am writing a Next.js api page that parse the data from a series of URLs. All of the URLs that contain the tick character `'` do not return data while the URLs that without it do return data. When I run the same code in Chrome's dev console or a RESTful Client, the URLs with the tick character `'` successfully return data. Both scenarios successfully connect (HTTP 200), but results are not found when running in Next.js project. Does anyone know what is causing this difference in behavior?

**UPDATES:**

1. I have tried both `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`. They do not fix the issue.
2. I have also tried using `AYR%27KA`. Does not fix issue.
3. When I compare the URL passed to `fetch` to the `response.url`, the values match in the browser but in Next.js `AYR'KA` changes to `AYR%27KA`.
4. After working with @Phil and doing a lot of digging, this issue is caused by Node.js's URL default component. Here is the NPM [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url) and here is the [link](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-url) to their github. When node-fetch builds a `Request` object, they call `URL.parse` on the passed string. Here is a [link](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-url/blob/master/url.js#L119) to `URL.parse` in the file "url.js" on their github. On lines 353-360, they escape all url component characters from an array named `autoEscape`. On line 70 where `autoEscape`, we can see that the apostrophe/tick mark character `'` is included in the list of always escaped characters with a comment acknowledging that this is being done despite it not being a restrict character. (NOTE: This update was made on July 24th 2021 and references line numbers and variable names of the latest version of the code at this time.)

***NOTE:** To prevent CORS, run in Browser Dev Tools from the site [here](https://robertsspaceindustries.com)

```
const worksEveryWhereURL = "https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/STANTON",
    brokenInNodeURL = "https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/AYR'KA";

async function getJSONFrom(url){
    const opts = {method: "POST"};
    let response, json;
    
    console.log("url: ",url)
    response = await fetch( url, {method:"POST"} );
    console.log("response url: ",response.url)
    json = response.json();

    return json;
}

function testResponse(json) {
    try {
        return json.data.resultset.length > 0;
    } catch(err) {
        return false;
    }
}

const example1 = await getJSONFrom( worksEveryWhereURL );
const example2 = await getJSONFrom( brokenInNodeURL );

console.log( testResponse(example1) ); //"true" in chrome and "true" in next.js api page
console.log( testResponse(example2) ); //"true" in chrome and "false" in next.js api page
//Output in browser console when run in browser:
//url: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/STANTON
//response url: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/STANTON
//url: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/AYR'KA
//response url: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/AYR'KA <-- matches before fetch
//true
//true <-- expected result

//Output in Command Prompt window when run in Next api page:
//url:  https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/STANTON
//response url: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/STANTON
//url:  https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/AYR'KA
//response url: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/AYR%27KA <-- why changed?
//true
//false <-- unexpect result, note change
```

Just for reference, here is the code that I am using as an api page that is returning an empty resultset:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const worksEveryWhereURL = "https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/STANTON",
        brokenInNodeURL = "https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/AYR'KA";

    async function getJSONFrom(url){
        const opts = {method: "POST"};
        let response, json;

        response = await fetch( url, {method:"POST"} );
        json = response.json();

        return json;
    }

    function testResponse(json) {
        try {
            return json.data.resultset.length > 0;
        } catch(err) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    const example1 = await getJSONFrom( worksEveryWhereURL );
    const example2 = await getJSONFrom( brokenInNodeURL );

    console.log( testResponse(example1) ); //"true" in chrome and "true" in next.js api page
    console.log( testResponse(example2) ); //"true" in chrome and "false" in next.js api page
}
//Output in Command Prompt window when run in Next api page:
//url:  https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/STANTON
//response url: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/STANTON
//url:  https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/AYR'KA
//response url: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/AYR%27KA <-- why changed?
//true
//false <-- unexpect result, note change
```

When the response returns incorrectly, it looks like this:

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "code": "OK",
  "msg": "OK",
  "data": {
    "rowcount": 0,
    "totalrows": 0,
    "estimatedrows": false,
    "pagesize": 0,
    "pagecount": null,
    "page": 1,
    "offset": 0,
    "startrow": 0,
    "resultset": []
  }
}
```

While a correct response looks like:

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "code": "OK",
  "msg": "OK",
  "data": {
    "rowcount": 1,
    "totalrows": 1,
    "estimatedrows": false,
    "pagesize": 0,
    "pagecount": null,
    "page": 1,
    "offset": 0,
    "startrow": 0,
    "resultset": [
      {
        "id": "398",
        "code": "AYR'KA",
        "description": "Primarily a military system focused on supporting, housing, and training Xi’an ground troops. Its close proximity to the Perry Line made it strategically important during the Human / Xi’an cold war. Once relations normalized, Xi’an forces from the Perry Line systems withdrew to here.  ",
        "frost_line": "179.10000000",
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**From Update 4:** Code snippets from [url.js on github](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-url/blob/master/url.js#L119) that are causing my target URL to be unreachable (not my code; code from a dependency's dependency).

-[Lines 56-70](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-url/blob/master/url.js#L70) including their comments:

```
/*
 * RFC 2396: characters reserved for delimiting URLs.
 * We actually just auto-escape these.
 */
delims = [
  '<', '>', '"', '`', ' ', '\r', '\n', '\t'
],

// RFC 2396: characters not allowed for various reasons.
unwise = [
  '{', '}', '|', '\\', '^', '`'
].concat(delims),

// Allowed by RFCs, but cause of XSS attacks.  Always escape these.
autoEscape = ['\''].concat(unwise),
```

-And here are [lines 348-361](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-url/blob/master/url.js#L354) including comments were the previous list of characters are used:

```
/*
 * First, make 100% sure that any "autoEscape" chars get
 * escaped, even if encodeURIComponent doesn't think they
 * need to be.
 */
for (var i = 0, l = autoEscape.length; i < l; i++) {
  var ae = autoEscape[i];
  if (rest.indexOf(ae) === -1) { continue; }
  var esc = encodeURIComponent(ae);
  if (esc === ae) {
    esc = escape(ae);
  }
  rest = rest.split(ae).join(esc);
}
```

Comment: You say they both respond with 200 so what data _is_ returned? Perhaps try `console.log("response text", await response.text())` to see exactly what you're receiving

Comment: Also, just to check, try changing the second URL to use `AYR%27KA`. It should be necessary but it's worth a try

Comment: @Phil, I have updated my question with the expected response and the incorrect response. And thanks for your suggest unfortunately I had already tried that. I have updated my quest to reflect this too.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, I've never used Next.js but is the code _any_ different in your _"next.js api page"_? I only ask as the response data is also empty if you use the URL ending at the `'`, ie `https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/starmap/star-systems/AYR`. Is the code above in your question _exactly_ the same?

Comment: @Phil, it's as exact as it can be. It only differs by the container it's in. I'm new to Next.js but I believe that since this is an api page the code is run inside of Node.js (the `console.log()` statements are showing in the Command Prompt window and not the browser console). 

And any call that can not be found returns an empty `resultset`.

Comment: Just before you run `fetch()`, can you please add `console.log("fetching URL:", url)`, just to make sure that the full URL is making it into your function.

Comment: @Phil, I have added `console.log(URL)` before the fetch and `console.log(response.url)` to my test. In the browser the values are the same. In Next.js the response URL changes to `AYR%27KA`. I have noted the new observation  in my question.

Comment: That's some excellent debugging, especially logging out the `response.url`. I think I've found the problem and a possible solution 

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be down to the version of `node-fetch` that's used by Next.js.

[The newer v3.x version (still in beta)](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/pull/701) use `new URL()` instead of Node's `url.parse()` which is what's causing the problem.

You might be able to work around this by using `new URL()` yourself which should avoid any parsing.

Try something like this

```js
async function getJSONFrom(url) {
  const response = await fetch(new URL(url), { method: "POST" })
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${await response.text()}`)
  }

  return response.json()
}
```

---

If that doesn't work (which after [looking at the code](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/v2.6.1/src/request.js#L52) I'm thinking it might not), try forcing `node-fetch@v3.0.0-beta.10`

In `package.json`

```json
"resolutions": {
  "next/node-fetch": "3.0.0-beta.10"
}
```

See https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

Comment: The first part did not work. I haven't tried the second part yes since I am not currently using yarn. I'm looking at npm options to override package dependencies first before adding another software package.

Comment: Oh sorry, the Next project seems to use yarn by default so I thought that's what you'd be using

Comment: No worries. I could have used either but I had used npm once before so I used that. Using several packages that are new to me already for this project.

Comment: I did some digging and fetch is not the root of the issue. Url is the issue. I updated the question with the details. I think I might be able to create a work around by writing a custom `Request` class that doesn't using the default URL to pass to `fetch` instead of a url string. I want to give you the points for the chosen answer so I'll let you know what the details are when I have them so you can update your answer.

Comment: If you look at the code I linked you'll see that even if you pass a full `Request` object, it still extracts the URL and runs it through `Url.parse()`. Only v3 versions of node-fetch don't do this